# The author makes an appeal to the reader's emotions

Tags: grammar

> The author makes ***an appeal to the reader's emotions***.

[Source](https://www.britannica.com/dictionary/appeal)

---

1. I'm not sure if "***an appeal***" is modified adjectivally by "***to the reader's emotions***" or if "***to the reader's emotions***" modifies "makes".
2. I'm not sure if "***an appeal to the reader's emotions***" is a noun phrase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is formally ambiguous, So it could be read the other way, but by far the most natural reading is as your 2: *an appeal to the reader's emotions* is a NP, the object of *makes*.

The fact that the noun *appeal* readily takes a complement with *to* encourages that reading; but I don't think there's any structural way to decide between the readings.

**Edit**: thinking about Aaaaaaassss's comment makes me realise that there is another reason to faviour that reading: *make* does not normally take a *to* complement. However, it is possible to argue that *make an appeal* does, so *makes-an-appeal [to the reader's emotions]* is a possible reading. (I'm not suggesting that we would ever write "makes-an-appeal" hyphenated, just trying to convey that for the purpose of that analysis they are effectively a compound verb).

Comment: How about "***He made an emotional appeal to voters***"? I wonder if this is also formally ambiguous.

Comment: It is formally and not actually ambiguous in the same ways.